# Displaying data from database with php that is meets requirements

Tags: php, mysql, html, json

I am designing an event feed from a calender I made. I'm using the same data from the database but to match specific dates and times.

1. I only want 4 events to show at once (why I specified `length < 4`)
2. Where the database value `'showFeed'` is true, it only displays those rows.
3. and I want it to show by date time, I have odd id's for each value in the database, which might make them out of order.

My current code:

```
$sql = "SELECT `title`, `time`, `start`, `showFeed` FROM calender WHERE length('column') > '0'";

$result = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "<div class=\"eventfeed\">";
echo "<ul>";

foreach ($result as $row){

$show = $row['showFeed'];

if ($show == 1 && length.$result < 4){
    echo "<li>";
    echo $row['title']. "<br />";
    echo $row['start'].' '.$row['time'];
    echo "</li>";
} 
else {

    return false;
}
}

echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";

$dbh = null;

echo json_encode($return);

?>
```

I'm getting results and no errors from the database, but I'm only seeing one return on `$results`.

I honestly, do not have a clue where else to go from here. I'm lost.

Comment: To show 4 at once shouldn't you be using `LIMIT 4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1+.2.+3. modify your query to `SELECT title, time, start, showFeed FROM calender WHERE length('column') > '0' and showFeed=1 and time<current_timestamp ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 0,3` and remove your `if (...)` statement.

Comment: amazing, now. the date comes out in "2012-05-01" format, is there a way to have it rewritten to with May 1, 2012 or Tues, May 1, 2012? I don't want it to show the events that have passed. Will this do it?

Comment: To format the date, you can use [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). I updated the query to reflect showing only rows with a time in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is your actual code, but you should determine the length of an array by doing $result.length instead of the other way around.

Also, you can limit the number of results in your query using 'LIMIT 4' at the end of your query. That way MySQL only returns 4 results and you don't have to worry about that in your code, just print everything.

Comment: Okay, I can limit it to 4, but then how would I get it to pull from this day forward by 4 events.